# Why am I getting a parser error on my YAML config in MongoDB --Install

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install the service for Mongodb. I am typing the following command in the cmd window, as administrator

```
c:/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install,
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Error parsing YAML config file: YAML-cpp: error at line 2, column 13 :
>   illegal map value

Here is the config file contents:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
```

Answer (score 14):

Well,
Note that YAML doesn't really satisfy with tabs, then, use space instead before destination and storage.
Don't forget to add a space after every ":" even in the lines systemLog and storage
Finally, use quotes to enclose your pathes and double backslashes in these pathes.

Try then with :

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: "c:\\data\\log\\mongod.log"
storage:
 dbPath: "c:\\data\\db"
```